# How can I add a user's domain information to the pipeline in PowerShell when using Get-ADUser?

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell

I'm trying to enumerate the name, samaccountname, and domain that each user in my forest belongs to and write it to a text file.

The script that I have now is:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$domains = "root.org", "child1.root.org", "child2.root.org"


ForEach ($d in $domains){

Get-ADUser -Filter * -ResultSetSize $null -Server $d -Properties name, samaccountname |
Select-Object name, samaccountname | out-file c:\users\mdmarra\desktop\users.txt -append

}
```

What I need is the value of $d at the end of each line as well so that the output looks like

```
name          samaccountname        domain
----          --------------        ------
Marra,Mark    mdmarra               root.org
```

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's something you can easily achieve with hashtables in `Select-Object`:

```
ForEach ($d in $domains){

Get-ADUser -Filter * -ResultSetSize $null -Server $d -Properties name, samaccountname |
Select-Object name, samaccountname, @{ Name = 'domain'; Expression = { $d }} | out-file c:\users\mdmarra\desktop\users.txt -append

}
```

Comment: Yep, that's perfect.